# SQL Server remote connection in connecting to (master) database

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, wildfly

I am developing spring app which uses SQL Server as a database engine, I was using SQL Server 2012 and everything was fine

Then I migrated to SQL Server 2016 the app works well from Intellij IDEA

But when I upload it to wildfly, the used database is the "master" database, although I'm using the same connection string

Is there any configurations that need to be changed in order to use SQL Server 2016 in wildfly

Thanks in advance

```
Intellij string
manage.doc.db.url = jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=document_springboot
```

```
wildfly string
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=document_springboot
```

**EDIT**

in the wildfly log I get this message

```
 Connection Properties for DataSource: 'java:/docManagementDatabaseSQLServer' is empty, 
try to use driver-class: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' and connection-url: 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=document_springboot' to connect database
```

Comment: I don't believe you need the `microsoft:` in the connection string. That might be defaulting to the master database.

Comment: Thanks for the response @WEI_DBA I removed it but no change, I'm still accessing the "master" database

Comment: Is the user credentials different connecting to `wildfly`?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm even specifying the same username and password for the database @WEI_DBA

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by referring to this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276738) 
I removed

`<datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>`

from the `standalone.xml` in the `datasource` tags